# I want to write some data into a .txt file using c++ / opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to save some information about every frame in a video to a `.txt` file.

The information could be like the current frame number, the position of the feature points etc,

I could only find ways to write it into a XML/YML file. Is it possible to write these into a .txt file? IF so, how ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Of course it's possible. A text file is probably the most basic file format. An XML file is basically a restricted form of text file.

Comment: OpenCV is irrelevant here. You need to search for "writing numbers to a file in c++". Obviously this problem has been solved in the past.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have to roll on your own implementation. The basic of c++ file streams are

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void writeSomething()
{
    ofstream outputfile;
    outputfile.open("data.txt");
    for (int i=0; i<10;i++)
        outputfile << i << endl;
}
```

Your question is not very clear, so you'd better edit it to be clear about what you exactly want to do.